# Run Google Cloud Storage gsutil command when terminal is closed

Tags: linux, gsutil

I am deleting a lot of files in a GS Storage bucket.  I am running `gsutil` from shell cmd like:

```
gsutil -m rm -r gs://bucket-name/folder-name
```

I found that when the shell session is over or I close chrome, the command is interrupted, even with `&` to run background. Any ideas about running command or script without being interrupted even the session is over?

Thanks

Comment: How do you know the command is interrupted?  Are you seeing an error message?  Are you running this on your machine, or in Cloud Shell?

Comment: I am running the cmd in Cloud Shell, online not on my local machine. I was deleting a lot of small files, would cost hours. I ran the cmd background but after several hours the files were not all deleted. So I am thinking that when the session expires, the cmd will be interrupted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running a command in the background with `&` does not prevent it from being killed when you logout or close the shell.  To prevent a command from ending when detached, run it with `nohup`.  For example:

```
nohup gsutil -m rm -r gs://bucket-name/folder-name &
```

Comment: Yes sir ... see the following ... https://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/   The high level is that when a terminal is disconnected, all processes started from that terminal are sent a SIGHUP (hangup) which will kill the command.  The nohup command takes a command as a parameter and disables SIGHUP delivery for that command.